# Web Scraping I am getting an index errror out of range for this piece of code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

For this below code I get the error when trying to scrape the data. this is when i try to loop the code from more then 1 page 1:2 and I try and change to anything above this amount [ERror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL1vR.png)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for page in range(1,3):
    link = 'https://www.theaa.com/used-cars/displaycars? 
fullpostcode=&travel=2000&page='+str(page)
    r = requests.get(link,headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.5'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    linksList =[]
    for link in soup.find_all('a',class_='black-link'):
        url = link['href']
        linksList.append('https://www.theaa.com/'+url)

data=[]
for i in linksList:
    page=requests.get(i,headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.5'})
    soup_inside = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    vehicle_values = soup_inside.find_all('span',class_='vd-spec-value')
    values=[]
    for v in vehicle_values:
        values.append(v.text.strip())

    mileage=values[0]
    year=values[1]
    fuel_type=values[2]
    transmission =values[3]
    body_type=values[4]
    colour=values[5]
    doors=values[6]
    engine_size=values[7]
    emissions=values[8]
    price = soup_inside.find('strong',class_='total-price new-transport--bold').text
    company = soup_inside.find('span',class_='make').text
    model =soup_inside.find('span',class_='model').text
    variant =soup_inside.find('span',class_='variant new-transport--regular').text

data.append([mileage,year,fuel_type,transmission,body_type,colour,doors,engine_size,emissions,price,company,model,variant])
```

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Please read [ask] and make sure your question has a [mre].

Comment: it looks like `values[8]` doesn't exist (index out of range). Have you inspected the contents of `values` to ensure it has at least the 9 elements you are indexing? Also if you are indexing lists that you don't know for sure how many elements will have you should then use `try / except` to catch cases like this.

Comment: it is more usable f'https://www.theaa.com/used-cars/displaycars? 
fullpostcode=&travel=2000&page={page}'

Comment: @Elkhan Thanks this has managed to solve it however I do not recieve more results when I increase the loop size from 1:2 to 1:3

Comment: I edited code. @DavidJohnZ There was a problem in your linklist.

Comment: If this is your answer mention it.

Comment: If it is your correct answer you can gave a tick for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you crawl all data as text then do your work with re or split, replace what you want. I added a sample.

```
data=[]
def parse(url):
    obj = {}
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'your bot 0.5'})
    soup_inside = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    df = soup_inside.select_one('ul.vd-specs-list.clearfix').text
    if 'Emissions' in df:
        obj['emission'] = df.split('Emissions:')[-1].replace("\n", '')
    else:
        obj['emission'] = np.nan
    obj['engine'] = df.split('Engine size:')[-1].split('Emissions:')[0].replace("\n", '')
    obj['urls'] = url
    data.append(obj)




for page in range(1,4):
    link = f'https://www.theaa.com/used-cars/displaycars?fullpostcode=&travel=2000&page={page}'
    r = requests.get(link,headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.5'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    linksList ={}

    a =  soup.find_all('a',class_='black-link')
    for az in a:
        url = az['href']
        aze = ('https://www.theaa.com/'+url)
        parse(aze)

your_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```